# Cannot reproduce client SQL 2008R2 error: subqueries are not allowed

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**EDIT: My question is not "how do I work around the failure?", my question is "why is the failure occurring?"**

We have a client that reports error "1046 subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed" for SQL Server 2008 R2.  We cannot reproduce in house.  Is there a server setting or database configuration option that can cause this?

-- Simplification of tables looks like this

```
create table foo_type(
    foo_type_id int not null,
    foo_type_name nvarchar(100) not null,
    primary key (foo_type_id)
)

insert into foo_type values (1, 'type one')
insert into foo_type values (2, 'type two')

create table foo(
    foo_id int not null,
    foo_type_id int not null,
    foo_name nvarchar(100) not null,
    primary key (foo_id),
    constraint fk_foo_to_foo_type
    foreign key (foo_type_id) references foo_type
)

insert into foo values (11, 1, 'foo one')
```

-- and the mysteriously failing insert

```
insert into foo values (
    (select coalesce(max(foo_id),0) + 1 from foo),
    2,
    'foo two'
)
```

Comment: Can you add real code please? Simplified code is almost always useless and it saves "I can't do that because...." later

Comment: The real tables and SQL are equivalent, just with more columns.

Comment: That doesn't help: What is the real INSERT table? Is there a WHERE? A GROUP BY to deal with the "more columns"? help us to help you.

Comment: There are no clauses.  This is the production statement, with less columns and different column names.

Comment: it seams that this code is not the place of problem

Comment: @garik, hence the question originally posed:  Is there a server setting or database configuration option that can cause this?

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @gbn. Something must be missing from the edited code.

Answer (score 3):

Are you 100% sure the `(select coalesce(max(foo_id),0) + 1 from foo)` gives one row? You said it was simplified code so this may not be the case.

This should be an IDENTITY column because 2 processes can insert the same row and you don't require an aggregate over the current data.

Anyway, how to fix it. Change to this (MAX without GROUP BY always gives one row)

```
insert into foo values (
select
    coalesce(max(foo_id),0) + 1,
    2,
    'foo two'
from
    foo WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
```

To test on the client, add this immediately after

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Note: the hints *reduce* (not remove) the chances of the same value being inserted.

Comment: The documentation for coalesce says it returns a single value:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx  Thanks for the identity tip, but this is being run from a single update utility while the main application is offline.  The error isn't a concurrent id problem, the statement won't execute at all on the client system, but works fine for me.

Comment: @Noalan: I asked "Are you 100% the ... gives one **row**?". It is nothing to with the COALESCE: you are scanning a table which can have **multiple rows** and this isn't **real code**

Comment: To extent I understand SQL, yes.  Max aggregates into a single row with a single column when one or many rows are present in foo, and the outer coalesce selects 0 over the returned null when the table is empty.  The only difference between this and the real code are the number of columns in the tables, and the column names.

Answer (score 1):

Do they have the database compatibility mode set correctly?  I'd check all the database options and compare them to what you expect from your systems.

Comment: It runs OK for me on 80, 90, 100 on an R2 install. Was my first thought.

Comment: Which compatibility mode setting are you referring to specifically?  I don't have direct access to the system in question because of legal requirements on access control.

Comment: The database compatibility mode.  Failing that I think we'll need more actual code to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I have never used INSERT with a sub-SELECT in that way.  This is what I would have done:

```
insert into foo 
select 
    coalesce(max(foo_id),0) + 1,
    2,
    'foo two'
from foo
```

That is, after all, the exact purpose for which that statement was made!

Or, if you *absolutely demand* to use the VALUES clause, you could try:

```
DECLARE @MaxId INT
SELECT 
    @MaxId = coalesce(max(foo_id),0) + 1
FROM foo

INSERT INTO foo 
VALUES (
    @MaxId
    2,
    'foo two')
```

I've never seen the "subqueries are not allowed in t his context" error, but I always use one of those two formats above (primarily the first on).

---

Regarding why this error is happening:  *SQL Server thinks that the sub-select will return more than one row*.  Whether it will or not is beside the point.  When SQL Server tries to parse the T-SQL for this statement, it is expecting multiple rows.

One more possibility is that you could add "TOP 1" to let SQL Server know that this will return only one row.  Personally, though, I would rather have the strange statement fixed than see a hacky workaround put in place.   But that's just my opinion.

Comment: thanks, we actually sent something like the latter as a manual workaround to the client yesterday.  The question still at hand is why did the insert with subselect fail in the first place?  It works fine for us, on the same version as the failing client server (SQL Server 2008 R2).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    insert into foo (foo_id,foo_type_id,foo_name)
    VALUES (
    (select coalesce(max(foo_id),0) + 1 from foo),
    2,
    'foo two'
    )
```

This should also work:

```
insert into foo
select coalesce(max(foo_id),0) + 1, 2,'foo two' from foo
```

Comment: I'll ask the client to try that manually out of curiosity, but the max() should already keep the statement from returning more than one row.

Comment: You're right. I missed the max completely.--Edited.

Comment: I can try using insert into..select instead, but I was hoping to understand why something that works on multiple installs here fails for our client with the same SQL Server version.